# database does not exist. Docker compose

Tags: python, linux, docker, docker-compose, asyncpg

В приложении использую пул подключений:

```
import asyncpg

async def create_pool():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool('postgresql://myuser:2233@db/telegramdatabase')
    return pool
```

После запускаю 2 контейнера с БД и Приложением через docker compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  bot:
    image: telegram_bot:1.0  # Имя образа бота
    command: /bin/sh -c "sleep 20 && python3 telegram_bot/bot/main.py"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - botnet

  db:
    image: mypostgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - botnet

networks:
  botnet:

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

В логах контейнера mypostgres после запуска docker compose вижу следующее:

```
FATAL:  database "myuser" does not exist
```

А логи docker compose показывают:

```
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidCatalogNameError: database "telegramdatabase" does not exist
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так? telegramdatabase существует 100%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «telegramdatabase существует 100%» — почему вы так решили?

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Какое отношение имеет этот скриншот к контейнерам?

Comment: Это внутри контейнера

Comment: да и через любой клиент postgres(dbeaver, pgadmin) подключиться к бд не составляет труда

Comment: А это точно **тот же самый** контейнер, который вы запускаете через docker compose, а не какой-то второй отдельно созданный?

Comment: да, точнее не бывает